# Getting a TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable PathCollection object. How to plot labels of different axis for bar chart and scatter in one legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I am receiving a TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable PathCollection object. I am trying to make a legend below the center of my graph for two axis. My combination plot is one bar chart and two scatter plots. I know this error is due to the lines for my scatter plots because of the ',' after b and c:

However I do not know how else to write them to make
p = [a, b, c] work. Thanks!

```
    df=df.set_index('Element')
    plt.errorbar(element_list,graph_gw_list, yerr=sd_list, linestyle='None', 
    barsabove= True, markersize=8, capsize=10)
    ax = df['Point'].plot.bar(figsize=(10,7))
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    
    a, = ax.bar(metal_list, graph_gw_list, color = 'yellow')
    b, = ax2.scatter(metal_list, risk_list, color = 'cyan')
    c, = ax2.scatter(metal_list, contam_list, color = 'green')
    # ax.set_ylim(min(graph_gw_list), max(graph_gw_list))
    plt.title(' Points per element')
    ax.set_xlabel('Element')
    ax.set_ylabel('Point)')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Screening level')
    
    ax.legend(['Point', 'Risk', 'Contaminant'])
    p = [a, b, c]
    ax.legend(p, [p_.get_label() for p_ in p],
       loc= 'lower center', fontsize= 'small')
    box = ax.get_position()
    ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0 + box.height * 0.1,
             box.width, box.height * 0.9])
   
    #ax.legend(loc='lower center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
      #fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: So you know where the error is coming from. You can't just write `a, = ...` if the right side is not an iterable that can be unpacked. Instead of posting sections of code that you know are wrong and that you know you can fix, please boil your question down to the actual problem you have.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Hi, my question is what code can I use/write to plot the labels of different y-axis (primary and secondary y-axis) for a bar chart and scatter plot together in one legend. So far, I have only been able to obtain the label of the bar chart in a legend--I would like it to have 'Risk, Point and Contaminant' instead of just 'Point'.